# How To Import and Read a Random SQLITE Database File (.db) from android device programatically?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to read random Sqlite database files from storage of Android devices just like SqlitePrime app is doing - i just want to fetch the records of the database file ,fetched from device storage

Comment: your question is not quite clear, please provide a code example of what you tried

Comment: I just wanted to import and read the Random SQLITE database file from Device Storage in Android
i have done it by myself though thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around for the problem:
After browsing the File on the device, do

```
 Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            try {
                String filePath=PathUtil.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
                SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(filePath, null);
                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + "Table", null);
                ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                int i = 0;
                result.add(cursor.getColumnNames());
```

Path Util Class

```
public class PathUtil {
/*
 * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    // deal with different Uris.
    if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

Comment: If this post answers your question, please mark it as accepted. So to remove your question from the Unanswered Question Queue.